# Shorten XPATH with wildcards

Tags: xpath, wildcard

I'm currently trying to figure out how to shorten my extremely long xpath.

```
//div[@class='m_set_part'][1]/div/div[2]/div[@class='row']/div[@class='col details detail-head']/div[@class='detail-body']/div[2]/div/div[@class='size']/div/div[@class='m_product_finder_size']/ul/li[1]/span[@class='size-btn']/a
```

This is the one I have right now and it's way too long, the problem is I need the first node to differentiate between products. Is there a way to shorten it like

```
//div[@class='m_set_part']/*/span[@class='size-btn']/a
```

Or do I have to go through all childnodes to reach the last nodes?

[Link](http://www.deichmann.com/DK/da/shop/home-sport/home-sport-stylekombinationer/00013000001533/Herre*Filas%C3%A6t.prod?r=5&c=3&filter_cat=/home-sport/home-sport-stylekombinationer)

I want to find the for each product the sizebuttons. The only way to differentiate them, I guess, is via adding a [1] or [2] to the m_set_part node.

Comment: well, without the data we can't really say if any shorter XPath yield the correct result. You can search for descendant-or-self nodes using `//`, i.e. `//a` would given you all a elements which are descending from the context element

Comment: I've updated it with more information, hope this helps to explain what I want to accomplish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically correct. As said in the comments, you can use `//` to select descendant or self nodes. Hence, this will give you all the size links:

```
//span[@class='size-btn']/a
```

As you suggest, you can select the specific product using a positional predicate. However, if you prefer you could also use another detail, e.g. the name. This would simply be

```
//div[@class="m_set_part"][.//label="Vælg"]
```

to given you the *Vælg* product.

Now combine them both and you can get the size link for this specifc product using

```
//div[@class="m_set_part"][.//label="Vælg"]//span[@class='size-btn']/a
```

or using the psoitional predicate it would be

```
//div[@class="m_set_part"][1]//span[@class='size-btn']/a
```

Also, please make sure you use a proper namespace as this is an actual XHTML document. One other thing is that you might prefer to use `contains(@class, 'm_set_part')` instead of `@class="m_set_part"` and the like, because the query will still work even if the add new CSS classes to this element.

Comment: I guess you're missing a dot in front if that `//label`?

Comment: What I meant is that a predicate of `[//label="Vælg"]` (with an absolute path) will either _always succeed_ (if the document in question contains any label with that value, whether or not it is inside the `div` being tested) or _always fail_ (if not).  If you want to select the `div` that _contains_ a label with that value then you need to use a relative path in the predicate, i.e. `[.//label="Vælg"]`

Answer (score 0):

To answer to your question: No you don't have to go through all nodes.

You may use the `//` descendant-or-self selector to 'skip' zero or more nodes in between the preceeding and the next part of the expression. So `//div[@class='m_set_part']//span[@class='size-btn']/a` might give you exactly what you want. `*` on the other hand matches any node, but exactly one node. Therfore

`//div[@class='m_set_part'][1]/*/*[2]/*[@class='row']/*[@class='col details detail-head']/*[@class='detail-body']/*[2]/*/*[@class='size']/*/*[@class='m_product_finder_size']/*/*[1]/*[@class='size-btn']/a`

is another way to shorten your original expression. Whether it's still returns only the interested node or more is solely depends on the document you apply the expression on.

Comment: That's not really a shorter expression, I'm afraid.

Comment: :D You are absolutely right! Thank you for your insight!